# Convert color PDF to black and white (monochrome) PDF in PHP [for Twilio Fax]

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, twilio, imagick

I am trying to convert a color pdf to black and white pdf. I am going to use the pdf to send it in **fax** and I am using Twilio and it is explicitly converting the color pdf to monochrome pdf however, I want to do it in my server-side to be able to preview the outcome.

As I have Imagick, and found some topics mainly on Imagick, I wanted to give it a try but I couldn't find the necessary class in Imagick. I found some for grayscale but fax is explicitly black & white (monochrome), so no identical to the fax case.

Closest I could find was:

`->transformImageColorSpace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB)` and

`->setImageColorSpace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY)`

But these are grayscale, not monochrome.

---

Also, on Imagick formums, I found these commands but I don't want to execute with `shell_exec` (as I've read there are couple of down-sides)

```
// I am pretty sure this one should work, but couldn't find how to do it in php:
convert -density 288 in.pdf -resize 25% out.png  

// thus this one:
convert -density 600 in.pdf -threshold 15% -type bilevel -compress fax out.pdf

// Also found this one:
convert -density 288 image.pdf -resize 25% -threshold 50% -type bilevel image.tiff
```

---

How to achieve what I am trying to achieve in php either using above commands or any other php compatible way? How does Twilio do it?

---

**Update:**

Expected output (how Twilio does it):

[image]

Using below answer:

```
$img = new Imagick('path/to/document.pdf');
$img->quantizeImage(2,                        // Number of colors
                Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY, // Colorspace
                50,                        // Depth tree
                TRUE,                     // Dither
                FALSE);                   // Error correction
$img->writeImage('path/to/output.png')
```

[image]

---

Update 2:

Using `$img->quantizeImage(2, Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY, 1, TRUE, FALSE);`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Imagick::quantizeImage`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.quantizeimage.php) to monochrome the PDF

```php
$img = new Imagick('path/to/document.pdf');
$img->quantizeImage(2,                        // Number of colors
                    Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY, // Colorspace
                    1,                        // Depth tree
                    TRUE,                     // Dither
                    FALSE);                   // Error correction
$img->writeImage('path/to/output.png')
```

For example...

```php
$img = new Imagick();
$img->newPseudoImage(300, 300, 'radial-gradient:');
$img->quantizeImage(2, Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY, 1, TRUE, FALSE);
$img->writeImage('output.png');
```

[image: output.png]

**

Or increase color count to allow gray values between black & white. See the usage docs [Color Quantization and Dithering](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/) for great examples.

```php
$img = new Imagick();
$img->newPseudoImage(300, 300, 'radial-gradient:');
$img->quantizeImage(255, Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY, 1, TRUE, FALSE);
$img->writeImage('output.png');
```

[image: output.png]

Comment: Thanks for your input @emcconville . I have updated my answer regarding your answer. Can you please check?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there any suggestions for how to do this with a multi-page pdf?

Comment: @Matthew, if you have a question, [please ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). The comment section doesn't offer the utility to answer correctly.